# html code not displayed the same in gmail message as in browser

Tags: html, css, gmail

I have this code that works great to remove the spaces between images but then when I embed it into a gmail message and send it, the receiver gets an email with spaces between images.

Anyone has any idea why it does that into gmail and not in a regular browser?

Thanks

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>img_test</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    table {
      border: none;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    table img {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table width="auto" border="0" border-spacing="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" height="auto" width="100%" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" height="auto" width="100%" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

But if I try the template done by professionals below it works perfectly fine on gmail, its mobile reponsive and no spacing everything is smooth.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" style="width:100%;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;padding:0;Margin:0">
     <head> 
      <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
      <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"> 
      <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting"> 
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
      <meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection"> 
      <title>New Template</title> 
      <!--[if (mso 16)]>
        <style type="text/css">
        a {text-decoration: none;}
        </style>
        <![endif]--> 
      <!--[if gte mso 9]><style>sup { font-size: 100% !important; }</style><![endif]--> 
      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <xml>
        <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
        <o:AllowPNG></o:AllowPNG>
        <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
        </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    </xml>
    <![endif]--> 
      <style type="text/css">
    #outlook a {
        padding:0;
    }
    .ExternalClass {
        width:100%;
    }
    .ExternalClass,
    .ExternalClass p,
    .ExternalClass span,
    .ExternalClass font,
    .ExternalClass td,
    .ExternalClass div {
        line-height:100%;
    }
    .es-button {
        mso-style-priority:100!important;
        text-decoration:none!important;
    }
    a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
        color:inherit!important;
        text-decoration:none!important;
        font-size:inherit!important;
        font-family:inherit!important;
        font-weight:inherit!important;
        line-height:inherit!important;
    }
    .es-desk-hidden {
        display:none;
        float:left;
        overflow:hidden;
        width:0;
        max-height:0;
        line-height:0;
        mso-hide:all;
    }
    [data-ogsb] .es-button {
        border-width:0!important;
        padding:10px 20px 10px 20px!important;
    }
    [data-ogsb] .es-button.es-button-1 {
        padding:10px 30px!important;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width:600px) {p, ul li, ol li, a { line-height:150%!important } h1 { font-size:30px!important; text-align:center; line-height:120%!important } h2 { font-size:26px!important; text-align:center; line-height:120%!important } h3 { font-size:20px!important; text-align:center; line-height:120%!important } .es-header-body h1 a, .es-content-body h1 a, .es-footer-body h1 a { font-size:30px!important } .es-header-body h2 a, .es-content-body h2 a, .es-footer-body h2 a { font-size:26px!important } .es-header-body h3 a, .es-content-body h3 a, .es-footer-body h3 a { font-size:20px!important } .es-menu td a { font-size:16px!important } .es-header-body p, .es-header-body ul li, .es-header-body ol li, .es-header-body a { font-size:16px!important } .es-content-body p, .es-content-body ul li, .es-content-body ol li, .es-content-body a { font-size:16px!important } .es-footer-body p, .es-footer-body ul li, .es-footer-body ol li, .es-footer-body a { font-size:16px!important } .es-infoblock p, .es-infoblock ul li, .es-infoblock ol li, .es-infoblock a { font-size:12px!important } *[class="gmail-fix"] { display:none!important } .es-m-txt-c, .es-m-txt-c h1, .es-m-txt-c h2, .es-m-txt-c h3 { text-align:center!important } .es-m-txt-r, .es-m-txt-r h1, .es-m-txt-r h2, .es-m-txt-r h3 { text-align:right!important } .es-m-txt-l, .es-m-txt-l h1, .es-m-txt-l h2, .es-m-txt-l h3 { text-align:left!important } .es-m-txt-r img, .es-m-txt-c img, .es-m-txt-l img { display:inline!important } .es-button-border { display:block!important } a.es-button, button.es-button { font-size:20px!important; display:block!important; border-width:10px 0px 10px 0px!important } .es-btn-fw { border-width:10px 0px!important; text-align:center!important } .es-adaptive table, .es-btn-fw, .es-btn-fw-brdr, .es-left, .es-right { width:100%!important } .es-content table, .es-header table, .es-footer table, .es-content, .es-footer, .es-header { width:100%!important; max-width:600px!important } .es-adapt-td { display:block!important; width:100%!important } .adapt-img { width:100%!important; height:auto!important } .es-m-p0 { padding:0px!important } .es-m-p0r { padding-right:0px!important } .es-m-p0l { padding-left:0px!important } .es-m-p0t { padding-top:0px!important } .es-m-p0b { padding-bottom:0!important } .es-m-p20b { padding-bottom:20px!important } .es-mobile-hidden, .es-hidden { display:none!important } tr.es-desk-hidden, td.es-desk-hidden, table.es-desk-hidden { width:auto!important; overflow:visible!important; float:none!important; max-height:inherit!important; line-height:inherit!important } tr.es-desk-hidden { display:table-row!important } table.es-desk-hidden { display:table!important } td.es-desk-menu-hidden { display:table-cell!important } .es-menu td { width:1%!important } table.es-table-not-adapt, .esd-block-html table { width:auto!important } table.es-social { display:inline-block!important } table.es-social td { display:inline-block!important } }
    </style> 
     </head> 
     <body style="width:100%;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;padding:0;Margin:0"> 
      <div class="es-wrapper-color" style="background-color:#F6F6F6"> 
       <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
                    <v:fill type="tile" color="#f6f6f6"></v:fill>
                </v:background>
            <![endif]--> 
       <table class="es-wrapper" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;padding:0;Margin:0;width:100%;height:100%;background-repeat:repeat;background-position:center top"> 
         <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
          <td valign="top" style="padding:0;Margin:0"> 
           <table class="es-content" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;table-layout:fixed !important;width:100%"> 
             <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
              <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0"> 
               <table class="es-content-body" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;background-color:#FFFFFF;width:600px"> 
                 <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                  <td align="left" style="Margin:0;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px"> 
                   <!--[if mso]><table style="width:560px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td style="width:270px" valign="top"><![endif]--> 
                   <table class="es-left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;float:left"> 
                     <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                      <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:270px"> 
                       <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"> 
                         <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                          <td class="es-infoblock" align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;line-height:14px;font-size:12px;color:#CCCCCC"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;line-height:14px;color:#CCCCCC;font-size:12px"><span style="text-align:center"></span>Put your preheader text here<span style="text-align:center"></span></p></td> 
                         </tr> 
                       </table></td> 
                     </tr> 
                   </table> 
                   <!--[if mso]></td><td style="width:20px"></td><td style="width:270px" valign="top"><![endif]--> 
                   <table class="es-right" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;float:right"> 
                     <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                      <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:270px"> 
                       <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"> 
                         <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                          <td align="right" class="es-infoblock" style="padding:0;Margin:0;line-height:14px;font-size:12px;color:#CCCCCC"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;line-height:14px;color:#CCCCCC;font-size:12px"><a href="https://viewstripo.email" target="_blank" class="view" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;text-decoration:underline;color:#CCCCCC;font-size:12px">View in browser</a></p></td> 
                                       <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"> 
                     <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                      <td valign="top" align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:560px"> 
                       <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"> 
                         <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                          <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#333333;font-size:14px"><span style="font-size:16px"><span style="font-family:'trebuchet ms', helvetica, sans-serif"><span style="line-height:150%">Sign up </span></span>and learn about stocks and hot offers. Also we publish interesting articles every week.</span></p></td> 
                         </tr> 
                         <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                          <td align="center" style="Margin:0;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-top:15px"><span class="es-button-border" style="border-style:solid;border-color:#2cb543;background:#47598b;border-width:0px;display:inline-block;border-radius:30px;width:auto"><a href="https://viewstripo.email/" class="es-button" target="_blank" style="mso-style-priority:100 !important;text-decoration:none;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:18px;border-style:solid;border-color:#47598b;border-width:10px 20px 10px 20px;display:inline-block;background:#47598b;border-radius:30px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;line-height:22px;width:auto;text-align:center">Sign up with Facebook</a></span></td> 
                         </tr> 
                       </table></td> 
                     </tr> 
                   </table></td> 
                 </tr> 
                 <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                  <td style="padding:0;Margin:0;background-color:#efefef;background-position:left top" bgcolor="#efefef" align="left"> 
                   <!--[if mso]><table style="width:600px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td style="width:300px" valign="top"><![endif]--> 
                   <table class="es-left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;float:left"> 
                     <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                      <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:300px"> 
                       <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"> 
                         <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                          <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;font-size:0"><img class="adapt-img" src="https://pzekhx.stripocdn.email/content/guids/CABINET_0e80a7555db07e59a031455280a74c7f/images/2261501079577592.adapt" alt="Palm beach Sydney" title="Palm beach Sydney" width="300" style="display:block;border:0;outline:none;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic"></td> 
                         </tr> 
                       </table></td> 
                     </tr> 
                   </table> 
                   <!--[if mso]></td><td style="width:0px"></td><td style="width:300px" valign="top"><![endif]--> 
                   <table class="es-right" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;float:right"> 
                     <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                      <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:300px"> 
                       <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"> 
                         <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                          <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-top:15px;padding-left:25px;padding-right:25px"><h3 style="Margin:0;line-height:24px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:20px;font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;color:#333333;text-align:left">Palm beach Sydney</h3></td> 
                         </tr> 
                         <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                          <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-left:25px;padding-right:25px"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#333333;font-size:14px">TO FANS OF EXCURSIONS</p></td> 
                         </tr> 
                         <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                          <td align="left" style="Margin:0;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;padding-left:25px;padding-right:25px;font-size:0"> 
                           <table width="10%" height="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"> 
                             <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                              <td style="padding:0;Margin:0;border-bottom:2px solid #cccccc;background:#FFFFFF none repeat scroll 0% 0%;height:1px;width:100%;margin:0px"></td> 
                             </tr> 
                           </table></td> 
                         </tr> 
                         <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                          <td align="left" style="Margin:0;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:25px;padding-right:25px"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#333333;font-size:14px">Palm Beach, or "Palmy", lies at the end of a long peninsula, fringed by surf on one side and tranquil Pittwater on the other.</p></td> 
                         </tr> 
                       </table></td> 
                     </tr> 
                   </table> 
                   <!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]--></td> 
                 </tr> 
                 <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                  <td style="padding:0;Margin:0;background-color:#efefef;background-position:left top" bgcolor="#efefef" align="left"> 
                   <!--[if mso]><table style="width:600px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td style="width:300px" valign="top"><![endif]--> 
                   <table class="es-left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;float:left"> 
                     <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                      <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:300px"> 
                       <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"> 
                         <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                          <td align="right" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-top:25px;padding-left:25px;padding-right:25px"><h3 style="Margin:0;line-height:24px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:20px;font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;color:#333333">Best of Paris</h3></td> 
                         </tr> 
                         <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                          <td align="right" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-left:25px;padding-right:25px"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#333333;font-size:14px">IDEALLY FOR COUPLES</p></td> 
                         </tr> 
                         <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                          <td align="right" style="Margin:0;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;padding-left:25px;padding-right:25px;font-size:0"> 
                           <table width="10%" height="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"> 
                             <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                              <td style="padding:0;Margin:0;border-bottom:2px solid #cccccc;background:#FFFFFF none repeat scroll 0% 0%;height:1px;width:100%;margin:0px"></td> 
                             </tr> 
                           </table></td> 
                         </tr> 
                         <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                          <td align="right" style="Margin:0;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:25px;padding-right:25px"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#333333;font-size:14px">This is the favorite place to visit over and over again! No photo or video can capture what you feel when you are next to it or under it.</p></td> 
                         </tr> 
                       </table></td> 
                     </tr> 
                   </table> 
                   <!--[if mso]></td><td style="width:0px"></td><td style="width:300px" valign="top"><![endif]--> 
                   <table class="es-right" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;float:right"> 
                     <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                      <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:300px"> 
                       <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"> 
                         <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                          <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;font-size:0"><img class="adapt-img" src="https://pzekhx.stripocdn.email/content/guids/CABINET_0e80a7555db07e59a031455280a74c7f/images/75111501079553681.png" alt="Paris" title="Paris" width="300" style="display:block;border:0;outline:none;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic"></td> 
                         </tr> 
                       </table></td> 
                     </tr> 
                   </table> 
                   <!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]--></td> 
                 </tr> 
                 <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                  <td style="padding:0;Margin:0;background-color:#ffffff" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left"> 
                   <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"> 
                     <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                      <td valign="top" align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:600px"> 
                       <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"> 
                         <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                          <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-bottom:10px;padding-top:25px"><h2 style="Margin:0;line-height:29px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:24px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;color:#333333">Lorem ipsum</h2></td> 
                         </tr> 
                         <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                          <td align="center" style="Margin:0;padding-top:5px;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px;padding-bottom:25px"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#333333;font-size:14px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitatio.</p></td> 
                         </tr> 
                       </table></td> 
                     </tr> 
                   </table></td> 
                 </tr> 
                 <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                  <td style="Margin:0;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;background-position:left top" align="left"> 
                   <!--[if mso]><table style="width:560px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td style="width:270px" valign="top"><![endif]--> 
                   <table class="es-left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;float:left"> 
                     <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                      <td class="es-m-p20b" align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:270px"> 
                       <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"> 
                         <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                          <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;font-size:0"><img class="adapt-img" src="https://pzekhx.stripocdn.email/content/guids/CABINET_3ede03beea8a58107b9bdc4e935fac00/images/82621501164735240.png" alt="Paris" title="Paris" width="270" style="display:block;border:0;outline:none;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic"></td> 
                         </tr> 
                         <tr style="border-collapse:collapse"> 
                          <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#333333;font-size:14px"><span class="product-name">Best of Paris</span></p></td> 
align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;line-height:120%;font-size:0;color:#CCCCCC"><a target="_blank" href="https://viewstripo.email/?utm_source=templates&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=tourism&utm_content=promo_newsletter" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;text-decoration:underline;color:#CCCCCC;font-size:12px"><img src="https://pzekhx.stripocdn.email/content/guids/CABINET_9df86e5b6c53dd0319931e2447ed854b/images/64951510234941531.png" alt width="125" style="display:block;border:0;outline:none;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic"></a></td> 
                         </tr> 
                       </table></td> 
                     </tr> 
                   </table></td> 
                 </tr> 
               </table></td> 
             </tr> 
           </table></td> 
         </tr> 
       </table> 
      </div>  
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: And also the auto adjustment of the images dont work anymore.

Comment: Only the images are displayed but the html code dont work at all

Answer (score 0):

you can use chrome's developer tool. like just copy your code written within body tag (exclude body ) and go to Gmail, compose and inspect the message section of composing and paste your code there.
Similarly, copy the code written within the style tag(exclude style) and paste into Chrome developer tool.
for more info use reference:[embed Html into gmail](https://www.gmass.co/blog/use-custom-html-in-gmail-compose-window/)

Comment: my understanding is that in gmail there are many coding restriction but i barely know how to code and I dont want to use a paid service like  stripo, I guess I'll have to learn. Thanks

Comment: You don't have to use paid service. You can do it free with the chrome developer tool.

Comment: but I dont know how to code thats the issue

Answer (score 0):

You have a basic code and asking why it isn't working as a bit complicated code. It obviously wont. HTML renders differently in emails than in browser because it depends on the email client.

You can use builders like stripo or unlayer or may others and export code for free. Don't copy paste that code into the mailer but test it through https://putsmail.com/